# Ruby on Rails sending 500 errors to Rollbar in a properly way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rollbar

In my Rails app I'm rescuing from all possible error, therefore it's possible that some 500 are not correctly sent to Rollbar and I want to fix it. I'm reviewing the documentation but without a meaningful answer.

**Edit:**

To be more clear, I have couple methods where I can handle all errors but in one place I've got something like this:

```
rescue_from :all do |error|
        title = Rails.env.production? ? 'Error 500' : error.message
        Rollbar.notify
        render_jsonapi_errors(
          title: title,
          status: 500,
          error: error
        )
      end
```

And I think I have to add some logic because in this case I don't send this message to rollbar because of this `rescue_from :all` (I cannot just delete this). Is there something like `Rollbar.notify` ?

**Edit2:**

After adding `Rollbar.notify` I don't see that app is trying to connect to the Rollbar

Output from `rails s`

> Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-05-17 17:09:56 +0200
>
> NameError - uninitialized constant ApplicationController::ActionVew:
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:4:in
>   `<class:ApplicationController>'
>
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:3:in`'
>   app/controllers/root_controller.rb:3:in `'
>
> Started POST "/__better_errors/5b518f578013d9ea/variables" for
>   127.0.0.1 at 2019-05-17 17:09:56 +0200

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: @bo-oz I want to ensure that error (500) are properly send to Rollbar

Comment: I don't think you are able to catch 500 errors, since Rails is indicating that is doesn't know how to handle the error. I think you need to identify what are causing those errors in the first place.

Comment: @bo-oz After my update maybe it will be more clear for you what I want to achieve

Comment: `Rollbar.notify` does indeed exist - can't you use that in this method?

Comment: @SRack I think it doesn't work, please check my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better_errors gem (shown in your output) swallows errors in development mode.

It's a common-enough problem that we have a section of our Honeybadger documentation specifically for it: https://docs.honeybadger.io/lib/ruby/support/troubleshooting.html#the-better_errors-gem-is-installed

Comment: After removed better_errors gem it works well but I'm still confused - should I use `Rollbar.notify` or `Rollbar.error` ? is there any difference?

Comment: According to the Rollbar docs, `Rollbar.error` is what you want: https://docs.rollbar.com/docs/ruby#section-usage